# Condensation on bathroom vent

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

MY bathroom vent goes directly into the attic space,no pipe. It is getting warmer outside and my attic is very hot. When the Air conditioning is turned on the vent fan drips. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Our two bathroom fans vent into the attic space and have done so since the house was built in 1970. We never get any dripping. However, we have a well ventilated attic. I am surprised it is dripping more during the a/c season. I would think there would be less dripping with the attic hot. We once did have have a drip from one fan, but it was due to a roof leak dripping onto the fan unit.

Comment: Warm air during the a/c season holds more moisture than cold air during the heating season. The a/c cools the fan and duct below the dew point, condensing water out of the warm moist attic air, causing the drips. Dumping more moisture into the attic by venting the bathroom into there only makes things worse and will cause mold, wood rot, and shorten the life of your roof. Kitchen fans, bath fans, and clothes dryers should all be ducted outside to remove the moisture from the building. See Phillipp's answer below about duct options.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to fix this properly is to run an insulated pipe from the bathroom fan to the exterior of the house. The pipe should be insulated to avoid condensation buildup on the outside of the pipe. It's mostly an issue if you have cold winters, but either way, probably good practice. The best way would probably be to run it horizontally, with a slight slope away from the fan, to an outside wall (shortest route possible).

The second best option is to run it up through your roof, which would likely be more involved as you would need to install the vent flashing properly to avoid roof leaks.

The third option, if nothing else will work, would be to run it out your soffit. They make special soffit vent caps for this. This can cause the moisture to be sucked back into your attic, which is why I would go with one the first two options.

The issue with your current setup is that you are constantly blowing large amounts of moisture into your attic, where it probably just stays. This will eventually cause issues with mold, or rotting up there. If you have cellulose insulation, that will break down from the moisture as well.

You should also ensure that there is a flap at the end of the run. Some fans have one built in as well. This keeps air from going through the pipe when the fan isn't running, but gets pushed open by the fan when it is.

Comment: *"you are constantly blowing large amounts of moisture into your attic, where it probably just stays"* Take this seriously. My first house vented into the attic. When I had my roof reshingled, a roofer crashed through the solid decking (the plywood that shingles are nailed into) into the attic. The moisture had softened up the wood over time, and I had to pay to replace all my solid decking. And of course, paid extra to install the roof vent for venting out the roof so it wouldn't happen again. Trust me, take venting moisture into the attic very seriously and get it fixed sooner than later.